# TextInput autoCorrect disabled but still showing suggested words as blanks

Tags: react-native

I am working on a form with React-Native. When I focus on the field and the keyboard shows up, I am seeing the suggestion line on iOS when it shouldn't.

My `TextInput` component is set with `autoCorrect={false}` but it's still showing the suggestion line above the keyboard with no words.

```
<TextInput
  autoCorrect={false}
  onChangeText={handleChange}
  value={value}
  ...{moreProps}
/>
```

I've tested both on simulator and real device. And I'm still seeing this empty line.

How can we prevent this suggestion line from showing up?

Thank you

[image]